# Image Dataset for Face Direction

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to create a face direction detection based on yolov5, is there any existing or does anyone know any image datasets available for face direction like left, right, front and back of the head. any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: get face landmarks and try pose recovery. -- if you're really hoping for a network to directly infer some kind of angle or tan(angle) from the picture, I guess you could do that... but you'd need data first. -- note that you're asking for recommendations. please review [help/on-topic] and perhaps also take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using datasets for head pose estimation:

https://paperswithcode.com/task/head-pose-estimation#datasets

Some examples: AFLW, AFLW2000-3D, BIWI

They contain images of faces labeled with 3 angles: yaw, pitch, roll.